# Having an issues with jquery .val in firefox

Tags: jquery, laravel, firefox

On my front end which uses jQuery I have a line of code

```
$('#stripeToken').val("test");
```

Which gives stripeToken the value of "test".

In my html I have a line

```
<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" id="stripeToken" value = ""/>
```

On the back-end which I am using Laravel

```
Log::debug(Input::get('stripeToken'));
```

The above line when I used chrome prints out "test".  However, in Firefox nothing prints out.  Why does Firefox have an issue and how do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Well i have tested your code locally in chrome and firefox and it prints test in input value.

Comment: try to clear cache and see if things differ

Comment: the jQuery code is wrapped inside `$(document).ready({...});` or not?Is it on top or bottom of the page?

Comment: @AlivetoDie, yes it is

Answer (score 0):

In the progression of loading content to a site, you should observe this:

- Backend - PHP
- Reaction/Action - JavaScript
- Design/View - HTML/CSS

This means that the backend will always be connected/rendered first and the JavaScript would follow before the design (HTML, CSS).

But sometimes we what our JavaScript to run *after* the page is completely loaded. In that case, you can use:

```
// pure js
window.onload

//jquery
$(function (){

});
```

An alternate syntax for the jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready({

});
```

I don't think FireFox has any issues.

Run

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#stripeToken').val("test");
    });
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" id="stripeToken" value = ""/>
```

Then

```
Log::debug(Input::get('stripeToken'));
```